# threading and exception handling

Tags: multithreading

Lets say I have 2 threads both executes piece of code one by one, 
an exception occurs in that piece of code for thread 1, there is no exception handling done in that code, would the second thread get a chance to execute that piece of code.

Comment: What do you mean by "get a chance"? That's not a technical term. You could code it in such a way that it will get a chance to do anything.

Comment: more correct way if the exception occurs for first thread what is the guarantee that second thread will execute that code since no exception handling is done.

Comment: What language are we talking about?  You need to provide a lot more information to make this question viable.

Answer (score 1):

An exception thrown in one thread **does not** affect the execution of code in another thread.

There are some situations where it *seems* like it does. For example, if something is passed as a `Future` to another thread, and an exception was thrown when the result of that future was calculated, the thread that calls `get()` on that future will get an exception. However, this is not one thread affecting the other. The exception is actually stored in the future, and the caller of `get()` throws it by itself.

But yeah, the answer is, it doesn't affect execution in the second thread..

**UPDATE:**
Response to the comment: true I don't know why assumed Java. Having said that, the concept of threads having their own stack and the concept of futures seems pretty ubiquitous. For example, Python and C++ have same concepts and they essentially behave the same way. I don't know a platform where threads affected each other like that (probably because it wouldn't make sense).

Comment: `Future` sounds like you are talking about `Java` although I have no idea what language the question is about.

Comment: @Gray: I think the concept of future and threads not affecting each other in that way is language agnostic. For example, Python and C++ has same concepts and they essentially behave the same way.